# Relaxation spectrum and time dependence of magnetic moments

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

Consider a thermally isolated ferromagnetic crystal above but near its Curie temperature in a bias field such that the magnetization is essentially saturated. Now remove the bias field as fast as possible so the transition can be considered adiabatic.

1. What is the spectrum of the induced voltage measured by an open circuit coil that is wrapped around the specimen, and how long will it take for the moments to the randomize, i.e. to achieve thermal equilibrium with the crystal lattice?
2. How will the results change for a single domain crystal?
3. Can you refer me to measured results?

Comment: *"Now remove the bias field as fast as possible so the transition can be considered adiabatic. "* Wouldn't removing the field quickly make the process *not* adiabatic?

Comment: @DanielSank By adiabatic I mean in a thermodynamic sense, i.e., adiathermal, no heat exchange between the specimen and the outside. I assume the bias field is removed fast enough so that during the relaxation there is no thermal leakage to the environment. I do not think this is an easy measurement for there must be some direct coupling into the measuring coil that I expect many orders of magnitude larger than the relaxation noise I am interested in.